# Waterproof Case Time Limits

Tags: water, diffusion

A lot of cellphone cases are rated safe for one hour at two meter depth.
I assume this is due to water molecule diffusion along **case seams** *(like
the zipped zipper in a ziplock bag)*, right?

- Is there a predictive model for such diffusion?

I'm surprised makers don't simply make the seams twiceas wide to allow twice the time, for example, so I am thinking the model ismore complicated than this.

Comment: I would never, ever subject my phone to such an experiment. How watertight a case is depends very much on how much dirt has gotten into seals. An entire high energy physics experiment was lost and hundreds of millions of dollars of research funding were not awarded once because one hair had gotten into a pressure seal. The electronics box drowned within hours, the funding agency folks who had warned against the design said "I told you so" and the entire field was set back for more than a decade.

Comment: Well there is the [diffusion equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_equation).

Comment: I moved this question to the engineering site and reworded it.